# Errors with web services in Apache CXF

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, web-services, soap

Now I am reading about Apache Axis2, Apache CXF, JAX WS and trying to make web service with Apache CXF. I am using Eclipse Kepler, JDK 7 and CXF-2.6.1. I am working on this tutorial http://www.javatips.net/blog/2013/11/create-jax-ws-web-service-using-eclipse.

I must admit that I am newbie in Web services. I am getting this error and I don't understand well. Could anyone help me please? Print from my console:

```
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;.
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:36 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:JAXWSEclipse' did not find a matching property.
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:36 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8099"]
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 589 ms
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:37 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\wtpwebapps\JAXWSEclipse\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec-1.1.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:37 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethodN(IntrospectionUtils.java:905)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.CallMethodMultiRule.end(WebRuleSet.java:1021)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1063)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1781)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2957)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1561)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1812)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1250)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:876)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [AxisServlet] and [cxf] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/services/*] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:293)
    ... 32 more

Jun 11, 2014 10:47:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/JAXWSEclipse/WEB-INF/web.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/JAXWSEclipse/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 49; columnNumber: 21; Error at (49, 21) : The servlets named [AxisServlet] and [cxf] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/services/*] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2711)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2743)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1066)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1781)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2957)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1561)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.parseWebXml(ContextConfig.java:1812)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1250)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:876)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [AxisServlet] and [cxf] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/services/*] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethodN(IntrospectionUtils.java:905)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.CallMethodMultiRule.end(WebRuleSet.java:1021)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1063)
    ... 25 more

Jun 11, 2014 10:47:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
SEVERE: Occurred at line 49 column 21
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/JAXWSEclipse] startup failed due to previous errors
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\CalculateWebService
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:38 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\CalculateWebService\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:43 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:43 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Jun 11 10:47:43 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:43 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/cxf-beans.xml]
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:43 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:43 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml]
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:43 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/cxf-beans.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:256)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1898)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:250)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 36 more
Jun 11, 2014 10:47:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/cxf-beans.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:256)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1898)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:250)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 36 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer given by Dinal works for CXF 2.3 and older.  For additional info: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/embedding-cxf-inside-spring.html

Answer (score 7):

The issue is `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Do the below to fix this issue:

- Download and add `cxf-rt-bindings-soap.jar` in your project.
- Do a clean build and deploy it again.

Comment: Thanks. Clean build of whole project resolved issue for me

Answer (score 0):

in WebContent/WEB-INF/cxf-beans.xml, remove import

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/ cxf/ cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
```